# Autorun a script on a bitlocked harddrive using Windows Task Scheduler once it's manually unlocked

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler, bitlocker

I'm trying to automatically restarts the Windows Explorer whenever I unlock my bitlocked internal HDD by password.

I thought about automatically calling a .bat file that restarts the explorer which I already created on my bitlocked HDD.

Now I thought about using the Windows Task Scheduler to create a task that triggers when the HDD is unlocked and then runs the file.
When creating a trigger, I'm using the "on an event" option to create a custom trigger.

Now my question is: How do I implement a XML filter that triggers whenever my HDD is unlocked?

Any help would be appreciated since I'm pretty new to XML scripts for Windows!